# Siyum on mishnayos by my bar mitzvah

Tags: mishna, bar-bas-bat-mitzvah, siyum

I have 10 months till my bar mitzvah and I have already finished Seder Zeraim, Seder Moed, Seder Nashim, Seder Nezikin and in Kadshim only Zevachim, Menachos Chulin and Kinim. How many mishnayos do I need to finish by my bar mitzvah?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Elliott and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 2):

Firstly mazal tov and yasher kochacho for taking on such a worthy endeavour!!!

The breakdown is as follows:

---

**Seder Kodshim (remaining masechtos)**

- Bechoros (9 perakim, 73 mishnayos)
- Erchin (9 perakim, 50 mishnayos)
- Temura (7 perakim, 35 mishnayos)
- Kerisus (6 perakim, 43 mishnayos)
- Meilah (6 perakim, 38 mishnayos)
- Tomid (7 perakim, 34 mishnayos)
- Middos (5 perakim, 34 mishnayos)

Sub total - 307 mishnayos

---

**Seder Taharos**

- Keilim (30 perakim, 254 mishnayos)
- Ohalos (18 perakim, 134 mishnayos)
- Negaim (14 perakim, 115 mishnayos)
- Parah (12 perakim, 96 mishnayos)
- Taharos (10 perakim, 92 mishnayos)
- Mikvaos (10 perakim, 71 mishnayos)
- Niddah (10 perakim, 79 mishnayos)
- Machshirin (6 perakim, 54 mishnayos)
- Zavim (5 perakim, 32 mishnayos)
- Tevul Yom (4 perakim, 26 mishnayos)
- Yadayim (4 perakim, 22 mishnayos)
- Uktzin (3 perakim, 28 mishnayos)

Sub total - 1003 mishnayos

---

So the total remaining amount is 307 + 1003 = **1310 mishnayos**